# RAM prediction that will be allocated for the mixed models calculation

Tags: memory, julia, profiling, mixed-models, data-fitting

Is it possible to at least approximately forecast the `RAM` capacity that will be needed to calculate the `mixed models` with `Julia`? (having information about the formula, dataset and server characteristics)


Of particular interest is the ability to predict the size of memory that will be needed for the fitting (`model = fit! (LinearMixedModel (formula, data), REML = true)`)